# Certificate Revocation List c#

Tags: c#, cryptography, certificate, x509certificate

I have a crl file.
I need to load it and work with it. It opens well by system.
Is there any way to do it without using WinAPi and 3rd party libs? 
I've tried to use `X509Certificate2` and `X509Certificate2Collection` `Import` method. I'm getting an error: 'Object not found'.
CRL is in PEM format (base64 encoding).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  There is no support for inspecting, editing, or composing a CRL with in-the-box types from .NET Framework.